# How to load uipickerview values from database in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to load data to uipickerview from database. 
this is my code

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(UsersDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
int i=0;
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
NSLog(@"select");
self.coun=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
 NSLog(@"Coun = %@",coun);

self.animals=[coun componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSLog(@"String value=%@",self.animals);
} 
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
} else
{
NSLog(@"not select");
}
```

and button actions code is

```
- (IBAction)selectAnItem:(UIControl *)sender {
//Display the ActionSheetPicker
[ActionSheetPicker displayActionPickerWithView:sender data:self.animals selectedIndex:self.selectedIndex target:self action:@selector(itemWasSelected::) title:@"Select Country"];
}
```

but it run load only last value. Not all values loaded in UIpickerview. How to load all values from database using this code. Anyone pls help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wat is ur animals object,Is tat Array.And how the coloum value of your DB will be?

Comment: animals is NSArray. coun is NSString

Comment: Does all ur animals values stored as single string in ur DB.Like animal1:anilmal2:animal3

Comment: yeah all values r printed in console. but last value only loaded in uipickerview.

Comment: i want to add string values into NSArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do like this,

```
NSArray *splitedString = [coun componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
NSString *animalName;
if ([splitedString count]>0)
{
        animalName=[splitedString objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.animals addObject:animalName]; //here animals should be NSMutableArray 
}
```

Comment: here animal is an NSArray. bcz 

- (IBAction)selectAnItem:(UIControl *)sender {
//Display the ActionSheetPicker
[ActionSheetPicker displayActionPickerWithView:sender data:self.animals selectedIndex:self.selectedIndex target:self action:@selector(itemWasSelected::) title:@"Select Country"];
}


It hav only NSArray

Comment: I think NSMutableArray can be passed for NSArray.

Comment: Why I am telling animals array as Mutable array, Bcz the array content should be added dynamically

Comment: I had passed NSmutableArray for the argument which need NSArray.Bcz NSMutableArray is Subset of NSArray only

Comment: k mutable array data used in above actionpicker how to use plz help me

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop, you have to collect all the `self.coun` values in an array. When you come out of the loop, having all the values, populate the picker.

```
NSMutableArray *countries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
    self.coun=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
    NSLog(@"Coun = %@",coun);
    [countries addObject:coun];    
    //self.animals=[coun componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    //NSLog(@"String value=%@",self.animals);
} 
// Now you can use countries to populate in picker.
```

You have to implement data source and delegates for the UIPickerView.

Seems, you are storing countries in DB, reading from DB you are assigning in self.animals. Thats kind of not matching things with variable names. And why are your parsing by ":"?

Comment: this is my console Output

2011-10-13 16:52:54.688 Aapkeapps[3381:207] select
2011-10-13 16:52:54.689 Aapkeapps[3381:207] Coun = India
2011-10-13 16:52:54.690 Aapkeapps[3381:207] String value=(
    India
)
2011-10-13 16:52:54.690 Aapkeapps[3381:207] select
2011-10-13 16:52:54.691 Aapkeapps[3381:207] Coun = America
2011-10-13 16:52:54.692 Aapkeapps[3381:207] String value=(
    America
)
2011-10-13 16:52:54.692 Aapkeapps[3381:207] select
2011-10-13 16:52:54.693 Aapkeapps[3381:207] Coun = England
2011-10-13 16:52:54.694 Aapkeapps[3381:207] String value=(
    England
)
Bt load nly one val n array

Comment: Whats are your database columns and their contents?

Comment: Column name is 'CountryName'

content is India,America,England

Comment: Then replace countries <-> animals. I would prefer the var name countries rather than animals :(

Comment: k but it not store in array only a last value stored